# checking result from select query then compare to current value if available then should not insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am saving latlong with the help of geolocation api into mysql db but problem is same latlong are inserted in database.I am trying to check last row of my mysql table and then comparing with current latlong if both are same,it should not be executed.Please help me to get this..Thanks in advance.

```php
 $latitude   =   19.1579;
 $longitude  =   72.9935;
 $address  =   airoli;


$sql = "SELECT latitude FROM tracklatlong ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $conn);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 $currentlat = $_row["latitude"];


 if($currentlat != $latitude){

 $query = "INSERT INTO `tracklatlong` (latitude, longitude,address) VALUES ('$latitude','$longitude','$address')";

     if($conn->query($query) === TRUE){
        echo "success";
    }
    else{
        echo "failed";
   }


 }

 else{


  echo"Already exists";


 }
```

Comment: so you want to check first lat long in db and then want to add

Comment: `$currentlat = $_row["latitude"];` =>  `$currentlat = $row["latitude"];`

Comment: Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the composite `(latitude, longitude)`.

Comment: @Anant yes last row of db want to check and if current latlong is same then should not insert.any idea??

Comment: @justbaron: Thanks fro reply but I didn't get you.

Comment: Print / echo the value of `$currenlat`....

Comment: @eggyal : thanks mate, but i can't do this because then user will not be able to update his address again. if he would come back return on same place again and again.

Comment: why last ? there can be more lat long entries already exists inside table right ? In short, You need to check if lat long pair is already exists in table, if not then insert right ?

Comment: @justbaron : Nothing comes when i did echo $currenlat .

Comment: There's your answer. You have a typo, `$_row['latitude']` should be `$row['latitude']`;

Comment: @rahul_m : What i want , Only last row of mysql table should not be same with the current because gps tracker repeatedly send same latlong again and again.If person went home from ofc today then its would show for today but what if he comes again on tomorrow?? that record should also get insert rgt?

Comment: @justbaron : I did       $currentlat = $row['latitude'];

echo $currentlat; but no echo of $currentlat

Comment: why lat only, long also need to check right ?

Comment: So your problem is in querying the database? If you are not getting any result from `$row['latitude']`, then you will always be inserting a new record...as `$latitude` (if it has a value) will never equal `$currentlat`

Comment: @justbaron yes you are right But I am trying this from past few days :(

Comment: @rahul_m yes you are right but I am trying to get my answer with latitude only

Comment: @justbaron I am able to get array of result using while loop and it does showing results bt what I am trying to do is to store result in  a variable first then comparing with current user values.

Comment: What is the value of `$row`?

Answer (score 0):

As understood you need to check weather the latitute or longitute is in `database Table` insert it only if found false.

I am using PHP Object oriented with mysqli prepared statements.

This code returns false only when both latitute and longitute are same.
if you want output to return false were any one matchs the output than just add `OR` operator in `SELECT` query.

Here is the table image with data

[image: tracklatlong table]

Here is html code :index.php

```
 <?php
    include('co_ordinate.php');
    $newcoordinate = new co_ordinate();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-top:100px;">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <i>Add Latitute</i>
                <input type="text" name="latitute" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <i>Add Longitute</i>
                <input type="text" name="longitute" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="addcoordinate" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['addcoordinate'])){
                $latitude = $_POST['latitute'];
                $longitute = $_POST['longitute'];

                $newcoordinate->getCo_ordinates($latitude,$longitute);
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the class file :co_ordinate.php

```
    <?php
    class co_ordinate{
        private $link;

        function __construct(){
            $this->link = new mysqli ('localhost','root','','example');
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                die("connection Failed".mysqli_connect_errno());
            }
        }

        function getCo_ordinates($latitude,$longitute){
            $sql = $this->link->stmt_init();
            if($sql->prepare("SELECT latitude,longitude FROM tracklatlong WHERE latitude=? AND longitude= ?")){
                $sql->bind_param('dd',$latitude,$longitute);
                $sql->execute();
                $sql->store_result();
                if($sql->num_rows > 0){
                    echo "The Co-Ordinates Already Exists";
                }
                else
                {
                    $query = $this->link->stmt_init();
                    if($query->prepare("INSERT INTO tracklatlong (latitude,longitude) VALUES (?,?)")){
                        $query->bind_param('dd',$latitude,$longitute);
                        $query->execute();
                        echo "The Co-Ordinates Inserted Successfully";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo $this->link->error;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```